# Knockout Mapping create callback called for every property with the same name

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mapping-plugin

Is there a way to stop Knockout Mapping from applying a create callback for every nested properties within a model?

Here is an example of the data and mapping passed to ko.mapping.fromJS().

```
var data = {
    name: 'Scott',
    level1: { 
        name : 'Alice',
        level2: {
            name: 'Tom'
        }
    }
}

var mapping = {
    name: { 
        create: function(options){
            console.log(options);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2LQut/

I want the create function to be called only for the top level, only for "Scott" and not for "Alice" and "Tom".

The only workaround I have found to achieve this is to add this to the create function.

```
this.create = null;
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I don't have control over the model property names. It is generated from C# objects.

Answer (score 1):

Use the "copy" option. See here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html#copying_certain_properties_using_copy

That would be something like this:

```
var mapping = {
    name: { 
        create: function(options){
            console.log(options);
        }
    },
    copy: "level1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of stoppig the create function being called, why not just perform the conditional logic inside it.

You have access to `options.parent` and `options.data` so just check to see where you are.

This is using a shopping cart item, but the same principle.

```
    var mapping =
    {
        'items':
        {
            create: function (options)
            {
                // does the 'item' contain a 'qty' property?
                if (options.data.hasOwnProperty('qty'))
                {
                    return new CartItemViewModel(options.data);
                }
                else 
                {
                    // it must be something else
                    return ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data);
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

OR for your example

```
    var mapping =
    {
        'name':
        {
            create: function (options)
            {
                // does the 'parent' contain a 'level1' property?
                if (options.parent.hasOwnProperty('level1'))
                {
                    console.log('we have the name we want');

                    // map it anyway
                    return ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data);
                }
                else 
                {
                    // it must be something else to just map it normally
                    return ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data);
                }
            }
        }
    };
```